# How to view the top scores in Nethack?

Tags: nethack

In Nethack, a list of top scores is displayed when dying, along with your position in the ranking.

Is there any other way to see this list of top scores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run the `nethack` command with the `-s` option:

```
$ nethack -s
```

On Windows, this might be

```
NetHack.exe -s
```

instead.

Comment: I can confirm that that is the Windows command, though the way it displays doesn't really seem to play well with the Windows command prompt.